# How to read variable sized characters from a file like input into stl string?

Tags: c++, string, stl

What is the basic technique to read variable sized character arrays from file into stl string. Currently I do it the 'bad' way.

1. read the count written during write
2. create a char array of that size plus 1
3. set the last element to zero
4. read into the buffer
5. assign it to the string
6. delete the buffer

Doing this in my application which processes many thousands of large character arrays is going to be slow. I can't pre allocate large buffer either because there is no upper limit set. Resizing the string first and reading into it seems non standard.

Please note that our application has a custom file library, so we can't rely on fstream, FILE etc. Also, we use stl and not boost.

What is the best technique to solve this?

Comment: "we can't rely on fstream, FILE etc."  means ?

Comment: The *best* technique would be to have your "custom file library" provide an iterator-to-the-next-N-bytes that you could pass to the `std::string` constructor. But that's likely far from the simplest technique.

Comment: Text file? Binary file? Provide more details about your data.

Comment: @p0w It means we can't use rbuf etc of fstream (which I came across while searching), or MemoryMappedFiles etc because our library doesn't have such notions as it is an abstraction.

Comment: @Casey and if performance are critical, the custom file library should load a large chunk of data at once from file (using a separate thread for i/o would also help)

Comment: Seems to me that this question (and any real answer to it) hinges almost completely upon the design of your I/O library -- about which you've told us nearly nothing.

Comment: So your file is a sequence of <size><unicode> pairs?

Comment: @JerryCoffin because it is a bit of a mystery to us as well lol It is one of those black boxes that is supposed to give a uniform file like behaviour on a variety of media. You are right about the issue hinging on it. We'll have to open it up and see if Casey suggestion can be incorporated.

Answer (score 2):

In C++11 (and in practice, in earlier versions as well), you
could read the count, resize the string, and then read directly
into `&str[0], str.size()`.  This avoids the dynamic allocation
of the buffer, and the extra copy.

Comment: I know you said 'in practice' but is it safe and reliable? Our code is supposed to be "standard" c++. The standard doesn't seem to say string has to be contiguous. Just that our code must be buildable on older versions of compliers as well so erring on the proper side here. Does c++11 mandate it to be contiguous?

Comment: @Dirt It's safe and reliable.  C++11 mandates contiguity, and that mandate was adopted because no known implementation didn't in fact have it.  (C++ did not originally require it, because there was intentionally a desire to leave a maximum of freedom open to implementers, and the idea that some might do something like the then widely known `rope` class.  None did, and the standard was changed to conform to existing practice.)

Answer (score 1):

If you know what size the string is going to have, then you could do something like this.

```
std::string str;

str.reserve( FILE_SIZE ); //if FILE_SIZE > str.size() then it allocates at least FILE_SIZE 

//you can query the capacity of you string calling

std::cout << "Capacity: " << str.capacity();
```

finally you have several methods to modify the string like push_back, resize, etc.

if you write something like

```
str[i] = 3;
```

make sure that the size of the string is at least i+1, you can change the size of the string through resize

```
str.resize(i+1);
str[i] = 3;
```

Take a look at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string to see more details.

EDIT: I hope you can understand me, I don't speak english, regards.

Comment: This is good but it doesn't solve my problem. I want to read directly into the string with minimal overhead with buffers etc. This solves the buffer issue but this will make me use non standard assumption about contiguous allocation of characters.

Comment: The standard make sure that the string allocates its data in contiguous memory, at least since C++11, otherwise, the member function data, could not exist, this function returns the internal NULL terminated byte string